# How to use a disk to system and a disk to storage CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, raid

I have a machine with two virtual drivers

1. 4 SSD with Raid 1 to mirror the OS
2. lots of HD with Raid 6 which I would like to use to store my files

When I installed the CentOS I choose to install only on the VD 1 and now I mounted the VD 2 in `/home/shared_` but it looks a little useless because mostly of people will save their stuff in `/home/user` which is a system folder.

Is there a way to use the system to be all in the VD 1 because it has a mirror and the user files be alway in the VD 2?

When I mounted the VD2(sdb) in the `/home` I get the following

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 333.4G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0 332.2G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 278.2G  0 lvm  /home
sdb               8:16   0  36.4T  0 disk /home
sdc               8:32   0  39.3M  0 disk
└─sdc1            8:33   0  39.2M  0 part
```

just to clarify `sda` is the VD1 and `sdb` is the VD2. At this point the folders from my old `/home` are missing, if I umount `sdb` it shows back. My problem is not with losing the folders that are there, my question is if when new users come their folder will be in the `/home` of `sda` or `sdb`? and the system will understand `/home` as which home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mount the VD 1 which is for the system on the mountpoint `/` (the root filesystem). That way, you ensure that your system is using the first virtual drive.

Then mount the VD 2 which is for the user files on the mountpoint `/home` directory, where all users will save their files.

EDIT: As you edited your post with the output of `lsblk` now, I see that you've actually had a virtual partition from VD1 mounted on `/home` as well. If you don't mind losing the files, you can simply `umount /home` till no partitions are mounted there, then `mount /dev/sdb /home`. After that, `/home` will be on `sdb` and `sda` won't have anything on `/home` anymore.

If you want to save your old files in `home`: Just `umount /dev/sdb` so only `sda` is on `/home`, then `cp -R /home /tmp`. (make sure `/tmp` dir exists before that)

After that `umount /home`, `mount /dev/sdb /home`.

Comment: if I mount VD2 in the /home I won corrupt the system dir by any mean?

Comment: No, you won't. Your system is in folders like /sys, /proc, /var and such. You mount VD 1 on `/` -> VD 1 is using all the system. When you mount VD 2 on `/home` (home is not a system folder and no system files are stored there), your user files will be on VD 2 (files saved in /home partition), and VD 1 will use all folders on `/` without `/home`. You won't corrupt your system.

Comment: I installed the OS in the VD1 and now mounted the VD2 in /home (which previously was part of VD1) but now whe I do "lsblk" I see the sda with /home and the sdb with /home in the mount point. VD1 is of the type lvm in this dir and VD2 is the type of disk. Is it ok?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If VD2 is mounted on `/home` and VD1 is mounted on `/` and everything works, it has to be fine. You've never referenced `sda`/`sdb` so I have no idea which is which and where it is mounted. I believe it is okay, but if you want, you can edit your question with the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: updated the post

Comment: @PatrickMachado updated my answer.

Comment: Hi I tried but I got `umount: /home: target is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))`

Comment: Try `sudo umount /dev/mapper/centos-home` to remove only `sda` from `/home`. @PatrickMachado (remember to close all applications before doing that, because most of them might write in `/home` and thus result in a partition being busy